# How to replace windows explorer action when user presses F3 (search)

Tags: windows, search, registry

I want to replace the action that is performed when a user presses F3 in Windows explorer. I want to run my own application (a custom search tool).

I am quite adept with win32s and the registry but I cant seem to see how other tools accomplish this functionality.